# Automating CiviCRM?

Tags: workflow

What kind of features and extensions are available for automating different tasks in CiviCRM?

I currently know of "scheduled reminders", CiviRules, and CiviCase.

I am looking for stuff that performs tasks like: if A happens, then perform B.

Comment: it might help if you clarify what sort of A and B you are after. I tried doing a 'when civi hangs, make coffee' but also failed ;-) If you are in Drupal you can also use Drupal Rules eg 'if I tag a contact as 'make Drupal User' then Drupal Rules can chug around and create the User and send the Drupal-style 'user account created' message etc

Comment: Questions that elicit lists of suggestions are not well-suited to the StackExchange format, which is intended to suss out a single "best" answer for the question. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help) and perhaps rephrase the question so that it can be answered definitively.

Answer (score 1):

You summed it up with

> "scheduled reminders", CiviRules, and CiviCase.